# Adding Xtext template proposals to the standard Templates View

Tags: eclipse, templates, xtext

We use a DSL generated with Xtext. We added template proposals to our editor as described in the [documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation.html#templates) , it works great - templates are available on 'Ctrl+space' and on the preferences page. However, they are NOT visible in the templates view - a standard view in Eclipse where the template proposals are usually displayed.

Normally, Eclipse templates are added by use of the org.eclipse.ui.editors.templates extension point, but it is not used in our plugin.xml generated by Xtext.

Is it possible to display Xtext templates in the standard templates view and if yes, how can we do it?

UPD:

As pointed by Zoltán in his comment, even though the templates view is placed inside the "Generic" group, it heavily depends on the JDT. That's a limitation of this view. An alternative approach to display all templates in a view next to the editor is described in [another post](http://eclipsesnippets.blogspot.fr/2007/07/quickfix-converting-preference-page-to.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the *General*/*Templates* view from the Show view dialog, as opposed to its category, is JDT-specific - at least according to the Plug-in spy it is contributed by the 
*org.eclipse.jdt.ui* plug-in, and it only displays Java related templates (I have other template-supported languages available in my setup, and none of them are displayed in the view).

In other words, even if it is possible to extend this list by the Xtext templates (but I think, it is not), you are to be very careful about it, as it might introduce potentitally unwanted JDT UI dependencies for your project.